# Show FPS in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game and I am trying to add a function to show the users FPS. I've been looking at some other questions on stackoverflow and other websites but they never seem to work for me. I would appreciate it if you answer. Thanks.

(Answered) - [View](https://darthvader1925.github.io/Fps/fps.html)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you think the other solutions don't work for you?

Comment: I've tried other stack overflow answers but I don't know if it is my computer or something but it doesn't work. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the below solution work for you?

```js
// 
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.ieRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

let fpsElement = document.getElementById("fps");

let then = Date.now() / 1000;  // get time in seconds

let render = function() {
    let now = Date.now() / 1000;  // get time in seconds

    // compute time since last frame
    let elapsedTime = now - then;
    then = now;

    // compute fps
    let fps = 1 / elapsedTime;
    fpsElement.innerText = fps.toFixed(2);

    requestAnimFrame(render);
};
render();
```

```html
<div>fps: <span id="fps"></span></div>
```

To know more about `requestAnimationFrame`, refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).